# How does C# Evaluate an array loop Boolean equilancy?

Tags: c#, boolean, bitwise-operators, boolean-expression

I'm trying to figure out why in the following method the last value in the array '8' would fulfill the where clause of "(8 & 7) == 0."

```
public class Test {
      public static void Main() {
             int[] Arr = {-3, -1, 0, 1, 3, 8};
             var s = from x in Arr where (x & (x-1)) == 0 select x+1;
             foreach (int x in s)
                    Console.Write(x + " ");
      } 
}
```

It's included on a recruitment skills test, and for the life of me I can't figure out why that value is selected.  Either way I won't be using it on my tests, but I'm curious since I've never run across this before.

Comment: That's a bitwise operator; it has nothing to do with booleans.

Comment: `8 & 1 == 0`, it is bitwise, the `==` part does a comparison and returns a boolean.

Comment: Study up on your bit manipulation.  8 & 7 == 0.  8 in binary is 1000 and 7 is 0111.  `And` those together and you get 0000.

Comment: Could someone please fix the spelling in the title?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So a single `&` is a bitwise operator. It's looking at those numbers binary representation.

7 = 0111 and 8 = 1000

When you combine them you get 0.

That is why your method prints out a 9.

Comment: Your 7 and 8 binary representation is backwards

Comment: Good catch. Corrected.